# Can anyone explain how this is concluded?

Tags: trigonometry

$$z=\sqrt{x^2-y^2}\tan{z\over \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}.$$
$$\tan{z\over \sqrt{x^2+y^2}}={z \over \sqrt{x^2-y^2}}$$
$$\cos^{-2}{z \over \sqrt{x^2-y^2}}={z^2 \over {x^2-y^2}}+1$$ I\m aware that the derivative of $\tan$ is $\cos^{-2}$ but the one right side is unclear to me, can anyone explain this last row, a little more carefully, much appreciated ?

Comment: It should be $\cos^{-2}\frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}$. $+$ not $-$ in the denominator.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have

$$
\tan^2 \frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{z^2}{x^2-y^2}
$$

and using identity $\tan^2 \theta= \sec^2 \theta -1$

$$
\sec^2 \frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}=\frac{z^2}{x^2-y^2}+1
$$

But note also that in the very first step division is valid given that $x\neq \pm y$. There are several points here and there  that you would like to pay attention with each implication, in general.

Comment: Only if $x=\pm y$, actually.

Answer (score 1):

If $\tan \theta = \dfrac ab$, $a,b > 0$, then $\cos \theta = \dfrac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}$ so that $\sec^2 \theta = \dfrac{a^2 + b^2}{b^2} = \dfrac{a^2}{b^2} + 1$.

With $\theta = \dfrac{z}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}}$, $a = z$, and $b = \sqrt{x^2 - y^2}$ you have
$$\sec^2 \frac{z}{\sqrt{x^2 + y^2}} = \frac{z^2}{x^2 - y^2} + 1.$$

Two comments: your last line has a typo, and $\cos^{-2}$ is not a good way to express $\dfrac{1}{\cos^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Do not differentiate *at all*. Because it follows directly from trigonometrical ratios:

$ \beta = \dfrac {z}{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}} $. Note that this angle is carried through.

Draw right angled  triangle $ ABC $. Mark on it angle $B$ as $ \beta $ and also

$$ AB = \sqrt{x^2-y^2 + z^2}  ,  BC = \sqrt{x^2-y^2}  , CA = z. $$

$$ \cos (\beta) = \frac{\sqrt{x^2-y^2}}{\sqrt{x^2-y^2 + z^2}} $$

and so, $$ \sec^2 (\beta) = \frac {x^2-y^2 + z^2} {x^2-y^2}$$